# ArrayField In Django is giving error while doing migrations

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-mysql

I have added arrayfield to model in my application. Below is my model

```
class employees(models.Model):
   firstName=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   lastName=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   tags_data = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),size=8,default=list)
```

Below is my migrations file data.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='employees',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('firstName', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('lastName', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('tags_data', django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=10), default=list, size=8)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

when I am doing migrate I am getting the below error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[8] NOT NULL)' at line 1")
```

What is wrong with the syntax. Please help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: On a side note, you used a trailing comma for `firstName`and `lastName`, and hence these are not seen as fields by Django.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayField is specific to Postgres, and is imported from a Postgres library.
All of these fields are available from the **django.contrib.postgres.fields** module.

Ensure your DATABASE configuration with Postgesql.
Looks like you're trying to commit your migrations to MySql. You should set up a local Postgres database, and update your settings.py file from.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'DATABASE NAME',
    'USER': 'USER NAME',
    'PASSWORD': 'USER PASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

And create your migration from your models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
# Create your models here.

class employees(models.Model):
   firstName=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   lastName=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   tags_data = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),size=8,default=list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any solution so that I can add arrayfield or listfield to my model for storing array of strings to my mysql db .

Comment: Yes definitely, You can use List Fields in MySql. Example 
tags_data = ListCharField(
        base_field=CharField(max_length=10),
        size=6,
        max_length=(6 * 11)  # 6 * 10 character nominals, plus commas
    )

refer this documentation https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html

Comment: I tried like this `ListCharField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=2),size=204,max_length=(204 * 3))`.  when I see the structure of my table it is showing as VARCHAR

Comment: p = Person.objects.create(name='Horatio', post_nominals=['PhD', 'Esq.'])
                                                                                                        
          p.post_nominals
                                                                                                                    
         ['PhD', 'Esq.']